# Absolute continuity on $[a,b]$ implies mapping of sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

I am reviewing some materials for real analysis and measure theory.

I want to show that if we have an absolutely continuous function on a closed interval, the function maps sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero.

I found the following that I have a few questions about, found at [http://www.ms.uky.edu/~perry/676-s19/_assets/final-answers.pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Eperry/676-s19/_assets/final-answers.pdf) on the last page :

[image]

- Where the author writes that $m(O) < \delta$, is this because $m(O) < m(E) + \delta = \delta$ ?
- How does the author assert that $f$ is continuous on each interval $[a_k,b_k]$ ? Since $Z$ is contained in $O$, can't it be that $[a_k,b_k]$ is not necessarily contained in $[a,b]$ ?
- Why can we conclude from $m(f(O)) = 0$ that $m(f(Z)) = 0$ ?

Thank you ! This is my first time here.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Because links tend to rot, would it be possible for you to transcribe the solution into the body of your question and give the source of the question/solution?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sure ! Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Where the author writes that $m(O) < \delta$, is this because $m(O) < m(E) + \delta = \delta$ ?

$\mathcal O$ is just chosen to be an open set containing $Z$ of measure less than $\delta$.  There exist open sets of arbitrary small measure containing $Z$.

- How does the author assert that $f$ is continuous on each interval $[a_k,b_k]$ ? Since $Z$ is contained in $O$, can't it be that $[a_k,b_k]$ is not necessarily contained in $[a,b]$ ?

If $S \subseteq T \subseteq \mathbb R$, and $f$ is a continuous function on $T$, its restriction to $S$ is always continuous.

- Why can we conclude from $m(f(O)) = 0$ that $m(f(Z)) = 0$ ?

They proved that given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $\mathcal O \subset [a,b]$ such that  $m(f(Z)) \leq m(f(\mathcal O)) < \epsilon$.  So for any $\epsilon >0$, we have $m(f(Z)) < \epsilon$.  This can only happen if $m(f(Z)) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So, just to clarify, the set $O$ is contained in $[a,b]$, correct ? And, did you mean to write $m(f(Z)) \leq m(f(O))$ ? In that case, how do we know this inequality is true ? Can we deduce this directly from $Z \subseteq O$ ? If we knew that $f(Z) \subseteq f(O)$, then I can certainly see it from there.

Comment: Yes $\mathcal O$ is contained in $[a,b]$, and yes $m(f(Z)) \leq m(f(\mathcal O))$.  Since $Z \subset \mathcal O$ it's of course true that $f(Z) \subseteq f(\mathcal O)$.